# Is it possible to manipulate the output of a laravel @yield in the blade template?

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

Wondering if it is possible to manipulate the output of a @yield in Laravel? In short I have a title in my child template that I would like to set some id's with to make them unique. I know I could just create another @section('id', 'asdf') but rather not have to worry users with that especially since the title has to be unique anyways...

Could not find anything that says this is possible?

Example (which fails) but what I am essentially trying to do:

```
id="{{Str::kebab(@yield('title'))}}-preview-tab"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@yield` gets replaced with a PHP `echo` statement so that is not what you want. If you want the content of a section you can grab it from the View Factory:

```
$__env->getSection($name, $default)
```

Or even calling `yieldContent`:

```
$__env->yieldContent($section, $default)
```

So you could try:

```
{{ Str::kebab($__env->getSection('title', 'some default if you want')) }}
```

If you have any issues with that, try the `yieldContent` method.

Comment: well I am not stuck with @yield... is there another way I could do this? Only thing I am seeing in the blade docs though...

Comment: and Yes I will try what you suggested above when i get a second.

Comment: sorry finally got a chance to test this - Worked like a charm! Thanks again!